# c++ Internet Interaction For DLL

Tags: c++, dll, game-maker

I am making a DLL to extend Game Maker, but it has to be written in C++.
I have most of the functionality I need (it does more than one thing), but I need to be able to connect to the internet, execute PHP files and get the results. I will also need to read files located on the internet.

It there any way to do something like this in C++ that will result in 1 DLL?

Oh, it also needs to be transferable to Mac OSX so I can compile a DyLib for use with GM4Mac

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost has a cross platform library for networking http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Answer (score 0):

39dll would be a good place to start as it comes with an example which downloads a file from the internet and if you point it to a php file it will return the results, the source code is written in c++ and is available here: http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=90437

39dylib is the mac version and is located here (also contains the source): http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=524126

Comment: Using 39dll should be actively discouraged. It is popular for historical reasons, but even its own author 39ster advises people to use other alternatives these days. It is buggy and makes applications needlessly complicated. For downloading files, you are better off learning from e.g. Maarten Baert's Http Dll 2 [link](http://www.maartenbaert.be/game-maker-dlls/http-dll-2).